# Updating java on a server

Tags: java

If a website is written in Java how does the server handle Java updates, does the admin need to take the website offline while the update is taking place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A usual practice are so-called rolling updates. The site is handled by multiple servers behind a load-balancer. While one system is being updated, the others have to share the load.

The update isn't automated per default, but surely can be.

Answer (score 1):

Update is not automatic nor necessary. If you do it, it is probably safer to stop your application server during the update.